# Xcode 7.11 Brew Boost C++ Library, Boost comple error

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I've tried to use Boost C++ library last a few days.
my every effort was failed, so Now I am typing keyboard to you.

Xcode project is simple project, hello, world.
see, below lines.

**my main.m** file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've installed boost with Homebrew.
and give search header path and lib path is

> /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/include
>   /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.59.0/lib

my error is like this.

circurla_buffer_fwd.hpp 'memory' file not found

[image]

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to include a C++ header into an Objective-C (not **Objective-C++**) file. Rename the file to `main.mm` (`.mm` for Objective-C++) and it should compile correctly